# Matrix differentiation for $(X'X)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a matrix-valued ODE $\frac{dX}{dt} = f(X)$ where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$.

My question is how could I obtain the ODE for $(X^\top X)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Is that in the form like $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dX}{dt}\right)^\top X (X^\top X)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}X^\top\left(\frac{dX}{dt}\right) (X^\top X)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: It's unclear what calculation you're attempting. Is $\sqrt{X^\top X}$ a choice of $f$? If so, why are you left-multiplying it by $\frac12\frac{df}{dt}$? What does any of this have to do with your ODE?

Comment: The square root of a matrix is not uniquely defined, you might want to add that everything remains in the space of positive semi-definite matrices. Also, the powers of your guess are wrong, the roots should have a negative power, similar to $(\sqrt {y(x)})'=\frac12y(x)^{-1/2}y'(x)$. I see the square root of spd matrices in symmetric directions evolving like \begin{align}
(A+εB)^{1/2}&=A^{1/4}(I+εA^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^{1/2}A^{1/4}
\\
&=A^{1/2}+\fracε2A^{-1/4}BA^{-1/4}+...
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry for my unclear statement. I have got the ODE for $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ with respect to $t$. Maybe the square root does not help anymore. What I wanna obtain now is the ODE for $X^\top X\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ with respect to $t$ using $dX/dt$.